# Git unstage committed files before push

Tags: git, github

I am trying to start over with adding and committing files before I push. Every time I type in `git push origin master -f` I get an error saying files are too big.
I want to unstage all files that are about to be pushed, so I can reselect the ones I want to push.  I tried

```
git reset --soft HEAD~1
git rm -r --cached . -f
```

Then I type `git diff --stat --cached origin/master` and still see all the files.  I have also tried `git reset HEAD` and also `git reset`.  Even after the resets I try to push and I still get the errors saying I am trying to push too big of file.  How do I reset this?  I want to keep all of the changes I have made on my local copy.

Comment: Random thoughts: after having used reset, does `git log --stat master` look OK to you, i.e. did you remove all commits you don't want to push (yet)? Also, `man git push` wants the flags before remote and refspec, do you get the same result with `git push -f origin master`?

Comment: I needed to do `git reset --soft HEAD~2`

Answer (score 0):

```
git reset -- *
```

unstages the files in the index, but leaves them in the working directory.

```
git reset --mixed HEAD~1
```

will also unstage files from the index when you reset the branch